# Update datagridview single cell value based on a condition

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

While the if statement is working when the condition is true, the else statement instead of staying on cell index 11 of the third row if goes on cell 11 of the first row. How can I make the else statement stay on cell 11 of the third row?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update VendorsReportSummary set Winning_Bidder = 'Hello' where Hospital_Id = ('"+textBox1.Text+"')", con);

if (textBox2.Text == "CHUM" || textBox2.Text == "Ste_Justine")
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

    vendorsReportSummaryDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value = "Bid Winner";
    vendorsReportSummaryDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
}
else
{
    vendorsReportSummaryDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value = "Winner not known yet";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help,I get the following error message:

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1061 'DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WindowsFormsApplication14 C:\Users\tythan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication14\WindowsFormsApplication14\Form1.cs 86

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to address a cell in a DataGridView is using:

```
int column = 11;
int row = 3;
vendorsReportSummaryDataGridView[column, row].Value = "...";
```

You can also use the name of the column, instead of its index, which is by far a better approach, for it points the same column even if it changes its index:

```
vendorsReportSummaryDataGridView["colName", 3].Value = "...";
```

**EDIT:**
You can, as well, use a longer but maybe clearer syntax:

```
//You can, as well, use a column index instead of column name
vendorsReportSummaryDataGridView.Rows[3].Cells["colName"].Value = "...";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I get the following error message:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Error CS1061 'DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I get a red squiggly under "Item"

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't read this earlier. I'll correct my code inmediately.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why I get a red squiggly under "Item"?